# AngularJS to php to json working inconsistently

Tags: php, angularjs, json, angular-services

I used AngularJS to make an app for grading students. It works perfectly 90% of the time, but every now and then, it doesn't record the data. The grade given or other change made will be reflected in the DOM, but disappears when the page is refreshed.

I use an angular service to send data to a PHP file which sends it to a JSON file. 
The service is set up like this:

```
app.factory('studentList', function($http) {

    var studentService = {};
    studentService.getInfo = function() {
        var promise = $http.get('../data/studentList.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    };

    studentService.sendData = function(data) {
    $http.post('../data/studentData.php', data)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
    });
};

    return studentService;

});
```

When I give a grade or change student info, I call the `sendData()` function defined in the service. This sends it to the PHP file which looks like this:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$file = "studentList.json";
file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

I've used this PHP code before, and it seems to work fine in everything else I've done. Any insights?

Thank you.

Comment: you should add a callback for error on your $http.post() to see what's happening

Comment: Too many unknowns here. Make sure you validate and add error handling on both ends

Comment: Changed the post request (reflected in the original code) so the console would log the status codes whenever a change was made. Getting status code 200 all the way down the line - although that's not completely unexpected given that it has always worked 90% of the time. Is it possible that the network I was on was having an effect on it? To connect to that particular network, a person had to manually configure their proxy settings.  Thanks again.